# Timing Analysis of Asynchronous Interface

Tags: timing-analysis

I have performed timing analysis for synchronous interfaces using clock signal. But how do we do timing of asynchronous interfaces where there is no clock??

To be precise, I am using P2020 from NXP & trying to perform timing analysis of local bus interface.

How do I start without having a clock signal?

Comment: Well if the bus doesn't have a clock it must have some kind of strobe, so the analysis would be related to it

Comment: It has Chip select, Output enable, Write enable, Latch Enable , Address & Data. I am not sure to which signal I can relate to?

Comment: I guess you will see the relationship of all the signals on the datasheet.

Comment: The P2020 local bus has a couple of quirks, but the datasheet is quite clear *provided you read the notes*. PLL bypass mode is far simpler to understand than the PLL enabled setup.

Comment: Have you thoroughly read the Reference Manual for the elbc (section 12)? The reference manual and the electrical datasheet need to be used together (as is usual with [what was Freescale] processors).